# Change/Override default message of validation attributes without using any culture or package

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm developing a web application using ASP.NET Core 2.1. I want to override/localize default data-annotations' error messages without using any package and external dependency or even culture. For example this is ***Mymodel***:

```
class Mymodel
{
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

When I submit the empty form it returns this default error:

> ***The {0} field is required.***  (in this case {0}= Email)

is there anyway to override/customize/change this default error for all [Required] data-annotations??

I **don't wanna** add *ErrorMessage* to my required data-annotation. Like this:

```
class ViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "my customized error message")
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Also I don't want to write my own data attribute.

I want something general. So wherever I use [Required] data-annotation, my customized error message will be shown.

I found this related question but it didn't helped me because no one answered the question.

> [How to provide localized validation messages for validation attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788092/how-to-provide-localized-validation-messages-for-validation-attributes)

I checked Microsoft docs. It wasn't clear

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2#dataannotations-localization

Comment: There is another problem here. I'm in a team. I made a subclass and other developers used the main class so that leads to disaster :((

Comment: It would need adapting for ASP.NET Core, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23179685) looks like it would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to comment, but I do not have enough reputation to do it. Apparently, what you are asking is not yet possible. There is a [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4848) in Github about this.